# how to send data with a link tag from a servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

In my servlet I do this :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String PatientName = request.getParameter("PatientName");

        PatientDB pdb = new PatientDB();
        ArrayList < Patient > p = new ArrayList < Patient > ();
        p = pdb.searchForPatient(PatientName);
        System.out.println("1st name: " + p.get(0).getName());
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
            String Name = p.get(i).getName();
            int ID = p.get(i).getID();
            s += "<a href='#' onClick=hideDiv('<%=" + Name + " >','<%=" + ID + " >')  >" + p.get(i).getName() + "</a><br>";
            //  (p.get(i).getID() + " , " + p.get(i).getName() + "<br>");
        }
        out.println(s);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

but I get corrupted output like that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take out the string concatination and look at the tag that you are building

```
s += "<a href='#' onclick=hideDiv('')></a><br>";
```

You can see that you are not enclosing the value of the onclick attribute properly in qoutes.

```
"<a href='#' onclick=\"hideDiv('')\"></a><br>">"
```

So with your string concatenation it would look like this:

```
s += "<a href='#' onclick=\"hideDiv('<%=" + Name + " >','<%=" + ID + " >')\"  >" + p.get(i).getName() + "</a><br>";
```

also not that the attribute name is onclick, not onClick